# Mapping the Clock in VHDL Constraint File

Tags: vhdl, vivado

So I have a VHDL program that relies on a clock for the processes, however I don't know how to place the clock in the constraint file. In my design source file, I declare the clock as

```
clk : IN std_logic;
```

I've tried a couple things based on what I've seen on the internet, like

```
create_clock -period 5 -name clk [get_ports clk]
```

and

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L16 [get_ports clk]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
create_clock -add -name clk -period 8.00 -waveform {0 4} [get_ports clk]
```

Neither have worked so far. The main error I keep getting is

```
Placer failed with error: 'IO Clock Placer failed'
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

I'm using Vivado 2015.2 and programing for the ZYBO board.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you were able to synthesize this design, I would check if 'clk' is in your netlist.  To do this, open the synthesized design and expand the "Nets" tree in the Netlist tab.  If 'clk' is not there, then it has optimized away; so recheck the VHDL if this is happens.

Also, you can type those constraints directly into the TCL console after you run synthesis.  By doing this, you'll get immediate feedback if Vivado was able to successfully execute the command or any errors it throws.  It's a quicker way to find errors so that you don't have to waste the time to "Run Implementation".

Comment: 'clk' is in the netlist. I tried using the clock wizard, so now I'm doing this with the clock - create_clock -period 10.000 -name clk -waveform {0.000 5.000} [get_ports clk]. - This is the main error I'm getting when I try to implement the design: - [Place 30-58] IO placement is infeasible. Number of unplaced terminals (1) is greater than number of available sites (0). The following Groups of I/O terminals have not sufficient capacity:  IO Group: 0 with : SioStd: LVCMOS18   VCCO = 1.8 Termination: 0  TermDir:  In   RangeId: 1  has only 0 sites available on device, but needs 1 sites. Term: clk

Comment: I don't think 'clk' is the problem.  I found the master .xdc for the ZYBO and all the pins are defined using the IO standard, LVCMOS33.  But the error is LVCMOS18; this implies that somewhere in the code, a signal has the LVCMOS18 IO standard associated with it.  This may happen if you haven't assigned that signal to a FPGA pin yet, so the tool automatically assigns it and assumes a default IO standard of LVCMOS18.  Check all signals have been mapped to a FPGA pin.